# User-Defined UML Data Types in Visio 2010

Tags: uml, visio

Is there a way to create custom types in Visio 2010?

We are creating a UML class diagram and need some of the properties to be defined as Dictionary, but that is not an option in Visio 2010 and it doesn't seem to allow creating custom types.

In Visio 2007, you could add a user-defined type: [Reference Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/add-data-types-to-a-uml-system-model-HP001208833.aspx)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Once you create a new UML project, on your left hand you see the Model Explorer window.

1. Right-click on the top file in there and select packages.
2. Add a new package (I have done it for a different language)
3. Right-click on the new created package in the Model Explorer.
4. New -> Datatype..

Comment: This is painful though to add all Java datatypes. Visio should provide generic data types also as UML should be language independent anyways.